# Javascript adding 2 video sources

Tags: javascript, html, video, mp4, webm

Hi I am very new to javascript. I have a .webm and .mp4 video source, but how can I add another source in javascript, I have only managed to put in 1 (webm), what is the code i need to add another one in?

Thank You in advance.

Hi, The reason why I need to put in JS is because divx plugin is replacing the html5 video elements, like on this thread [Prevent divx web plugin fron replacing html5 video element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745626/prevent-divx-web-plugin-fron-replacing-html5-video-element)

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changevid() {
    document.getElementById('vid').innerHTML = '<source src="http://avalonplay.com/video/loginvideo.webm" type="video/webm" />';
   document.getElementById('vid').load();
}
</script>

<body onload="changevid()">

   <video id="vid" width="800" height="450" loop="loop" preload="auto" autoplay style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0; right: 0;">    
   </video>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you only add the one that you need.

For example:

```
function changevid() {
   var vid = document.getElementById('vid');

   if (vid.canPlayType('video/mp4') != '') {
      vid.src = 'http://avalonplay.com/video/loginvideo.mp4';
   }
   else if (vid.canPlayType('video/webm') != '') {
      vid.src = 'http://avalonplay.com/video/loginvideo.webm';
   }
   vid.load();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.appendChild()` instead of `.innerHTML`

But a better solution would be to test for browser support and then only add the supported video type:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var vid = document.getElementById('vid');
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    var supported = supportedVidType();

    source.src = 'http://avalonplay.com/video/loginvideo'+supported.src
    source.type = supported.type

    vid.appendChild( source );

}

var supportedVidType = function(){
    var vidTest = document.createElement( "video" )

    var types = {}

    if ( vidTest.canPlayType ) {
        // Check for MPEG-4 support
        types.mp4 = "" !== vidTest.canPlayType( 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.8"' )

        // Check for Webm support
        types.webm = "" !== vidTest.canPlayType( 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' );

        // Check for Ogg support
        types.ogg = "" !== vidTest.canPlayType( 'video/ogg; codecs="theora"' );
    }

    for( type in types ){
        if(types[type]) {
            return {
                type: 'video/'+type,
                src: '.'+type
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2gd3m/2/

Answer (score 0):

the video tag supports multiple sources:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

from: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Hi, The reason why I need to put in JS is because divx plugin is replacing the html5 video elements, like on this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745626/prevent-divx-web-plugin-fron-replacing-html5-video-element

Comment: mhhhhh.. and it is because of you permissive programmer that the divx-people win..!!!!
shame on you!!!!!!!