# Visual Studios 2010: html5 video tag getting converted to embed tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, iis, html5-video

I am using BigVideo.js (http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) in my web project but when I run it in Visual Studios 2010, my video tags are getting converted into embed tags in Chrome.  I am using modernizr 2.6.2, and I have

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
</staticContent>
```

included in my web config.  I have also added .mp4 into my IIS express MIME types section for good measure.  I also tried using a program such as handbrake to use different codecs while encoding the video (MPEG-4 and H.264).

Is there a setting I need to set in my Chrome specifically? or maybe I need something else in my IIS or web.config?  I'd also like to point out that the BigVideo site itself does not work in my Chrome, but if you download the examples with static HTML, those do work... so that's what led me to believe that it wasn't a Chrome issue necessarily.

Any help would be appreciated... thank you!

Comment: Do you have the DivX browser plugin installed, by any chance? It has a habit of hijacking video tags and turning them into embed tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745626/prevent-divx-web-plugin-fron-replacing-html5-video-element/11863466#11863466

Comment: @brianchirls ugh... you are right!